# How to write tableofcontents.tex

Tags: table-of-contents

I should write tableofcontents.tex file for book  for Elsevier.  Please, give an example of latex format for this file.

Comment: Did you ask Elsevier for an example file?

Comment: Most document classes will cause a file `\jobname.toc` to be created if you request `\tableofcontents` at an appropriate place near the beginning of your document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}

\let\oldfinalMaketitle\finalMaketitle % Store \finalMaketitle
\renewcommand{\finalMaketitle}{% Update \finalMaketitle to...
  \oldfinalMaketitle % ...call original \finalMaketitle and...
  \tableofcontents\vspace{\baselineskip}} % ...add ToC.

\begin{document}

\title{Article of Test}
\author{John Smith}
\ead{email@email.com}

\journal{Science Now}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Key\sep Key\sep Key.
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[4-5]

\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[6-7]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[8-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]